# Using special character \ddagger in matplotlib equation label without latex

Tags: python, matplotlib, latex

As the title said I would like to use the matplotlib equation rending (not switch to latex rending via the rc options) in title and label equations, because it is much faster and I like the font and style. However it seems that it does not support the $\ddagger$ symbol. I am getting the error:

```
Unknown symbol: \ddagger (at char 31), (line:1, col:32)
```

Interestingly all other symbols, as also \dagger work. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `\ddagger` symbol has the unicode `2021`. So using the STIX fontset (find a table of all symbols [here](http://ctan.space-pro.be/tex-archive/fonts/stix/doc/stix.pdf)) you should be able to write it as

```
ax.set_title(u"\ddagger $\u2021$")
```

[image]